# Vim movement on other programs

Tags: linux, vim, user-interface, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm learning Vim and with it came the urge to use 'hjkl' and friends on every other program, including mouse operated programs like browsers.

How can I use these keyboard shortcuts, or something similar?

I'm using Linux.

Comment: Thanks all, I'm writing this with Vimperator..

Comment: Totally awesome topic. Let the Vim march towards Earth domination begins!

Comment: Most of the Vimperator developers have forked it and are now developing it as Pentadactyl (see http://dactyl.sourceforge.net/pentadactyl/index).

Comment: This would probably be better suited to SuperUser.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Off the top of my head...

- Vimperator for Firefox.
- Awesome, WMII, Xmonad or ion3 window manager.
- Evince supports hjkl.
- vifm filemanager
- there are vi keybindings for readline, which enables them for many terminal apps
- xzgv image viewer

Comment: I would also add:
mpd + ncmpc: music
dwm: another window manager

Comment: This answer should be wiki so we can add links to the relevant software ;)

Comment: +viplugin for eclipse (http://www.viplugin.com/viplugin/)

Comment: I prefer [Vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/) to viplugin, as it also preserves eclipse keybindings. With Vrapper you can use the normal eclipse bindings to start unit tests and such but retain the advantages of vi in normal text editing.

Answer (score 10):

Gmail and several of the other Google apps natively support Vi-like motions.

Also, you might want to try [Vimperator](http://vimperator.org/trac/wiki/Vimperator) and, most definitely, Nethack!

Comment: +1 nethack is most definitely productivity software.

Comment: @Vijay, `jk` takes you through conversations.

Answer (score 6):

Give [scrotwm](http://freshmeat.net/projects/scrotwm) a try. It's a tiling window manager with vim-like bindings by default, written by coders who use vim!

And [vimperator](http://vimperator.org/trac/wiki/Vimperator) for Firefox makes my life much, much easier.

For Bourne-like shells (ksh, bash, ...) try `set -o vi` to make your command line use vi keys.

Answer (score 6):

File manager with *vi* movement key-bindings and much more: [ranger](http://ranger.nongnu.org/).

Answer (score 5):

If you use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), then [viPlugin](http://www.viplugin.com/viplugin/) is the best vi-like editor for it.

I always stick the following two lines in my /etc/inputrc (or ~/.inputrc if I don't have root access):

```
set editing-mode vi
set keymap vi
```

Answer (score 5):

Others:

- [ViEmu](http://www.viemu.com/): plugin for Visual Studio, Word, Outlook, and SQL Server
- [Komodo Edit](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-edit/): developer's editor
- [AbiWord](http://www.abisource.com/): word processor
- [Editra](http://editra.org/): developer's editor
- [VimPlugin](https://vimplugin.org/): plug Vim into Eclipse. I couldn't get it working under Windows or Mac OS X.
- [Eclim](https://eclim.org/): another Vim plugin for Eclipse.
- [Viper](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ViperMode): Old vi emulator for Emacs
- [Evil](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil): Recent Vim emulator for Emacs
- [IdeaVim](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/164-ideavim/): Vim emulator for the [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) family of editors, [RubyMine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#RubyMine), [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyCharm), etc.

Comment: [**Evil**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil) for Vim emulation in Emacs is virtually flawless. It will probably replace Viper as Emacs' built-in Vim emulator relatively soon (I use it constantly :)

Comment: I've been using Evil for several months, in preference to Vim itself.

Answer (score 5):

[Zathura](http://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/) is a nice and small pdf reader and with built-in vim-like commands. 
It feels like you opened your pdf document in vim. (e.g.: the ':' button brings up the same prompt.)

Answer (score 4):

Viper works, but if you're used to Vim, it is lacking a lot of keybindings that will end up messing you up. Theres also [jvi](https://jvi.sourceforge.net/) for Netbeans, which I find more complete than the Eclipse plugins. Kate also recently added [Vi-emulation mode](https://web.archive.org/web/20120401032937/http://hamberg.no/erlend/2008/11/24/the-vi-input-mode-for-kate-is-done/)

I also consider [xmonad](https://xmonad.org/), to be superior to Awesome, Ion etc.

Comment: [**Evil**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil) for Vim emulation in Emacs is virtually flawless. It will probably replace Viper as Emacs' built-in Vim emulator relatively soon (I use it constantly :)

Answer (score 4):

[Okular](http://okular.kde.org/), the PDF reader of KDE 4 supports HJKL.

Answer (score 3):

[Vimium](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb) for Google Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

Lightweight (30k zpi) [FimFx](https://web.archive.org/web/20181102004024/https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimfx/) for Firefox - does less than Vimperator, but for a good reason.

Answer (score 3):

Check out:

- [dwb](http://portix.bitbucket.org/dwb/) — a web browser
- [ranger](http://nongnu.org/ranger/) — a terminal-based file manager
- [Zathura](https://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/) — a PDF viewer
- [Vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb) — a vim keybindings extension for Chrome(ium)
- [Evil](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil) — the (in)famous Emacs plugin that turns Emacs into Vim, if you ever feel the need to do that
- [i3](http://i3wm.org/), [xmonad](http://xmonad.org/), [dwm](http://dwm.suckless.org/) — tiling window managers that are controlled from the keyboard

Answer (score 2):

For xpdf, add these to your `~/.xpdfrc`:

```
bind h any scrollLeft(35)
bind l any scrollRight(35)
bind k any scrollUpPrevPage(35)
bind j any scrollDownNextPage(35)

bind ctrl-f any scrollDownNextPage(320)
bind ctrl-b any scrollUpPrevPage(320)

bind ctrl-d any scrollDownNextPage(160)
bind ctrl-u any scrollUpPrevPage(160)

bind g      any gotoPage(1)
bind G  any gotoLastPage
bind /          any find
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use xmodmap to make win+hjkl to work as arrow keys.
Make a file named Xmodmap. Add the following content:

```
keycode 133 = Mode_switch
keysym j = j J Down
keysym l = l L Right
keysym h = h H Left
keysym k = k K Up
```

Load it using xmodmap Xmodmap
Note: Run xev to find out keycode for win key. 133 is just an example.

Answer (score 2):

Qutebrowser hasn't been mentioned, which is much better than the plugins.

Answer (score 1):

I used [Ion](http://modeemi.fi/~tuomov/ion/) as a window manager on Linux for a while.  It uses keybindings similar to Vim to move between windows, if I recall correctly.  It won't make your apps support hjkl movement, but the window manager is a place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the already mentioned, you could also bind those keys to left... nd so on (with ahk). I've also noticed that several web apps use that movement keys (gmail, greader, ....)

Answer (score 1):

Try keynav, for controlling the mouse pointer using your keyboard.

http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/keynav/

Answer (score 1):

VisVim for Visual Studio
CubicleVim for outlook

Answer (score 1):

If you use mpd for listening to music, then I strongly recommend [PIM](http://pms.sourceforge.net)

Comment: Also, there's muttator for thunderbird

Comment: [Finch](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using Finch) uses [GNT](http://developer.pidgin.im/doxygen/dev/html/group__gnt.html) which can be configured to behave like vim (e.g. jkhl)

Answer (score 1):

`Google Reader` respects `jk` keybindings. I'm sure there are more that they support - feel free to edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Shortcut Manager](https://web.archive.org/web/20120119132624/https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf) extension for chrome.

You can use something like this to configure  basic vim movement keys:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @ShortcutManager
// @name Scroll up by 25 pixels
// @key k
// @include *
// @exclude https://*mail.google.com/*
// @execute ScrollUp(["25"])
// ==/UserScript==
```

Other useful snippets:

```
// @key g
// @execute ScrollToTop([])
 
// @key Shift+g
// @execute ScrollToBottom([])
```

Answer (score 1):

Mutt - mail client - can be configured to move hjkl, i configure some more vim keys. take some time to configure as it's a bit different from other mail clients. Mutt is not Muttator, is a terminal GUI application.

Answer (score 1):

cVim for chrome is awesome. I am currently using it.
https://github.com/1995eaton/chromium-vim

Answer (score 0):

**[How to get Vim keybindings in Adobe Reader on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/40909/vim-like-navigation-on-adobe-acrobat-reader/)**

(my answer to that question is an AutoHotKey script that will even get you proper search functionality with <kbd>/</kbd>, <kbd>n</kbd>, and <kbd>N</kbd>, but admittedly I haven't verified a port to Linux or Mac yet)